# Idris proof by definition

Tags: proof, idris

I can write the function

```
powApply : Nat -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
powApply Z f = id
powApply (S k) f = f . powApply k f
```

and prove trivially:

```
powApplyZero : (f : _) -> (x : _) -> powApp Z f x = x
powApplyZero f x = Refl
```

So far, so good. Now, I try to generalize this function to work with negative exponents. Of course, an inverse must be provided:

```
import Data.ZZ

-- Two functions, f and g, with a proof that g is an inverse of f
data Invertible : Type -> Type -> Type where
  MkInvertible : (f : a -> b) -> (g : b -> a) ->
                 ((x : _) -> g (f x) = x) -> Invertible a b

powApplyI : ZZ -> Invertible a a -> a -> a
powApplyI (Pos Z) (MkInvertible f g x) = id
powApplyI (Pos (S k)) (MkInvertible f g x) =
  f . powApplyI (Pos k) (MkInvertible f g x)
powApplyI (NegS Z) (MkInvertible f g x) = g
powApplyI (NegS (S k)) (MkInvertible f g x) =
  g . powApplyI (NegS k) (MkInvertible f g x)
```

I then try to prove a similar statement:

```
powApplyIZero : (i : _) -> (x : _) -> powApplyI (Pos Z) i x = x
powApplyIZero i x = ?powApplyIZero_rhs
```

However, Idris refuses to evaluate the application of `powApplyI`, leaving the type of `?powApplyIZero_rhs` as `powApplyI (Pos 0) i x = x` (yes, `Z` is changed to `0`). I've tried writing `powApplyI` in a non-pointsfree style, and defining my own `ZZ` with the `%elim` modifier (which I don't understand), but neither of these worked. Why isn't the proof handled by inspecting the first case of `powApplyI`?

Idris version: 0.9.15.1

---

Here are some things:

```
powApplyNI : Nat -> Invertible a a -> a -> a
powApplyNI Z (MkInvertible f g x) = id
powApplyNI (S k) (MkInvertible f g x) = f . powApplyNI k (MkInvertible f g x)

powApplyNIZero : (i : _) -> (x : _) -> powApplyNI 0 i x = x
powApplyNIZero (MkInvertible f g y) x = Refl

powApplyZF : ZZ -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
powApplyZF (Pos Z) f = id
powApplyZF (Pos (S k)) f = f . powApplyZF (Pos k) f
powApplyZF (NegS Z) f = f
powApplyZF (NegS (S k)) f = f . powApplyZF (NegS k) f

powApplyZFZero : (f : _) -> (x : _) -> powApplyZF 0 f x = x
powApplyZFZero f x = ?powApplyZFZero_rhs
```

The first proof went fine, but `?powApplyZFZero_rhs` stubbornly keeps the type `powApplyZF (Pos 0) f x = x`. Clearly, there's some problem with `ZZ` (or my use of it).

Comment: That's because you also pattern-match on `i`, which is not in weak head normal form. Try to replace pattern-matching on `i` with a case-expression. Or you can rewrite your signature as `powApplyIZero : (f : _) -> (g : _) -> (eq :  _) -> (x : _) -> powApplyI (Pos Z) (MkInvertible f g eq) x = x`.

Comment: @user3237465, thanks, but neither of those suggestions worked. By the way, why do you suggest a `case` expression? I thought that pattern matching/`with` was the canonical way in proofs. (I tried both the `case` expression and pattern matching on the left hand side.)

Comment: I suggested to use a case-expression (or an auxiliary function), because sometimes it's useful to delay forcing an argument to be in whnf, but yes, that's unrelated to your question. I added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem: `powApplyI` was not provably total, according to Idris. Idris' totality checker relies on being able to reduce parameters to structurally smaller forms, and with raw `ZZ`s, this doesn't work.

The answer is to delegate the recursion to plain old `powApply` (which is proven total):

```
total
powApplyI : ZZ -> a <~ a -> a -> a
powApplyI (Pos k) (MkInvertible f g x) = powApply k f
powApplyI (NegS k) (MkInvertible f g x) = powApply (S k) g
```

Then, with a case split on `i`, `powApplyIZero` is proven trivially.

Thanks to Melvar from the #idris IRC channel.

Answer (score 1):

`powApplyI (Pos Z) i x` doesn't reduce further because `i` is not in weak head normal form.

I don't have an Idris compiler, so I rewrote your code in Agda. It's pretty similar:

```
open import Function
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Integer

data Invertible : Set -> Set -> Set where
  MkInvertible : {a b : Set} (f : a -> b) -> (g : b -> a) ->
                 (∀ x -> g (f x) ≡ x) -> Invertible a b

powApplyI : {a : Set} -> ℤ -> Invertible a a -> a -> a
powApplyI  ( + 0     ) (MkInvertible f g x) = id
powApplyI  ( + suc k ) (MkInvertible f g x) = f ∘ powApplyI  ( + k ) (MkInvertible f g x)
powApplyI -[1+ 0     ] (MkInvertible f g x) = g
powApplyI -[1+ suc k ] (MkInvertible f g x) = g ∘ powApplyI -[1+ k ] (MkInvertible f g x)
```

Now you can define your `powApplyIZero` as

```
powApplyIZero : {a : Set} (i : Invertible a a) -> ∀ x -> powApplyI (+ 0) i x ≡ x
powApplyIZero (MkInvertible _ _ _) _ = refl
```

Pattern-matching on `i` induces unification and `powApplyI (+ 0) i x` becomes replaced with `powApplyI (+ 0) i (MkInvertible _ _ _)`, so `powApplyI` can proceed further.

Or you could write this explicitly:

```
powApplyIZero : {a : Set} (f : a -> a) (g : a -> a) (p : ∀ x -> g (f x) ≡ x)
              -> ∀ x -> powApplyI (+ 0) (MkInvertible f g p) x ≡ x
powApplyIZero _ _ _ _ = refl
```

Comment: The problem seems to be Idris-specific. It just refuses to reduce `powApplyI (Pos 0) (MkInvertible f g p) x = x` (what the type of the metavariable is, verbatim).

Comment: @James Wood, and the first definition of `powApplyIZero` doesn't typecheck too?

Comment: Yeah, it gives the same type each time, saying “Can't unify `x = x` with `powApplyI (Pos 0) (MkInvertible f g p) x = x`” when I try to fill the hole with `Refl`.

Comment: @James Wood, looks like a bug. Have you tried to write `Refl` without refining the hole? AFAIK, Idris doesn't have a deeply incorporated notion of metavariables like in Agda, so it might be a problem with holes.

Comment: I did some more testing, so I'll edit the question. In short, the problem is with `ZZ`.